# close emacs from remote computer

Tags: emacs, ssh

I forgot to close *emacs* at work which has buffers which are not saved.

Is there a way to close *emacs* from my remote computer using an ssh connection with forcing *emacs* to save all buffers?

Comment: Is Emacs running as a server? If so, then yes: connect with emacsclient, and do whatever you wish to do. If not, then I'm not aware of any way to do this unless Emacs reacts to a particular signal by saving buffers, which seems unlikely -- that's what autosaves are for, after all. (Basically I recommend always running Emacs as a server, just in case.)

Comment: @phils: well, it seems I didn't start it as a server...but thank you!

Comment: add (start-server) into your init.el - it's mandatory :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can kill the Emacs process from a shell. Emacs will have produced auto-save information for all file-related buffers.

Then start a new emacs, type `M-x recover-session`, and you will see a list of recent sessions to recover.

Type `C-c C-c` on the latest and [follow instructions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/After-a-Crash.html).